# Add padding to an image to make it square using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I've been given a folder full of images with products on white backgrounds and asked to make they're all square and all have a consistent amount of padding around the products.

I'd like to avoid resizing the image itself so my plan is to trim the image, add padding make the image square, then add a border to the image as a percentage of the resulting image.

The only part I haven't been able to figure out is how to do the padding. All the examples of squaring images I have seen resize the image in the process. Is there no way to find the longest size and resize based on that?

Example:
I have the following image:
[image]

I need it to look like this:
[image]

I have no code for ImageMagick yet (beyond the simple trim and the border command). The idea is to trim off the whitespace, then make the image square, leaving the product (in this case a rectangular black box) in the center of the image. Finally, the border is added to provide padding to the image.

Comment: Please give a concrete example of an image and how it is supposed to be squared and padded - also what code you have so far

Comment: I've added an example image and my desired output.

Comment: So your trimmed image is 629x157 - correct? How do you know it should become 758x758?

Comment: I used a calculator. In ImageMagick I will add a 20% border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get trim box w, h, x, y
IFS=" x+" read w h x y < <(convert -fuzz 10% start.jpg -format "%@" info:)

# Get longest side
longest=$w
[ $h -gt $longest ] && longest=$h

# Increase by 20%
longest=$(echo "scale=0;$longest*1.2/1" | bc)
echo $longest

convert -fuzz 10% start.jpg -trim -background white -gravity center -extent ${longest}x${longest} result.jpg
```

If you are not that familiar with *"bashisms"*, you can run

```
convert -fuzz 10% start.jpg -format "%@" info:
```

to see what that first command is doing - it just gets the trim box without actually trimming. Try adding this line after it:

```
echo $w, $h, $x, $y
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it works. I'll try and tweak it a bit so I can run it over a directory of images. I had tried fx:max(w,h) when defining my extent size but this doesn't work. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Using this method will break inside of a for loop. I found that a different way of getting the width can be: w=`identify -format '$w' $i`

Answer (score 0):

With Linux as shell script:

```
for file in *\.png ;  # or jpg,....
    do  IMG_W=$(identify -ping -format '%w' $file); 
    IMG_H=$(identify -ping -format '%h' $file); 
##   echo "$file: w: $IMG_W x h $IMG_H"; 
##   do something like
##   DIN A5: 2331x3307 pixel 400 dpi
##   half the width of white border
#   XPLUS=$(echo " ( 2331 - $IMG_W ) / 2 " |bc) ; 
#   YPLUS=250                                     
##   250 pixel from top border
##   echo "position: Xplus $XPLUS Yplus $YPLUS";
##   according to the calculations combine with white picture (background)
#   composite -geometry +$XPLUS+$YPLUS $file white.png ../tmp7/$file;
done
```

The example (comented out) shows you how to calculate and merge with a file. I don't know from which source I got the 2 lines of the script above (which is part of a script I've written), I think from Anthony Thyssen on his excellent site "Examples of ImageMagick Usage".

Answer (score 0):

This code is from Mark Setchell answer to this question, rewritten in fish shell script. I used his solution to add padding around the image to make it square.

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
convert -fuzz 10% $argv -format "%@" info: \
          | string split x \
          | string split + \
          | read -L w h x y

set longest $w
[ $h -gt $longest ] && set longest $h
set longest (math -s0 $longest\*1.2)

set output_file result-000.png
[ -f $output_file ] \
  && echo "file $output_file already exists" \
  || echo "file $output_file will be created" 
[ -f $output_file ] \
  || convert -fuzz 10% $argv -trim -background white -gravity center -extent {$longest}x{$longest} $output_file
```

Save as file, as example `frame.fish`, give it execute permission, `chmod +x frame.fish`, and run with a file `./frame.fish imageinput.png`.

`string split` will parse into different line by each delimiter. `read -L` will read into each line. `math -s0` produce zero scaled decimal in fish shell.